# du displaying strange file size, seems to follow some awkward size count rule

Tags: centos, disk-usage, watch

I'm facing something I can't explain to myself on a CentOS 7 VM.

I'm watching a log file which is growing at a ~100KBps rate.

I have a `watch` calling `du` but the output is always a power of 2, like in the following capture of the console :

```
Every 2s: 
du -k out.log
Sat Jan  4 14:26:25 2020

2097088 out.log
```

So, displaying the size in KB or MB or anything that changes in my console would satisfy me, like the regular 15M, 16M, 17M... and so on. I just want to see that the file grows. The unit is not important.

But what i get is e.g. 16M, 32M, 64M, ... 256M, 512M ... without intermediate steps. Each time the value changes, twice the previous time has elapsed as the file has to grow twice as big for the change to be visible.

If I use `-b` there is no problem, I see the size growing each 2 seconds.

I searched in the man pages like [this one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) but I don't understand why I can't see the "real progression" using the option `-k`.

I'm sure I missed something in the docs, but I can't figure out what.

Thanks all for your time and investment in this community.

**EDIT**

Running again this command `watch du -k out.log` :

- 4 (first value at call)
- (waiting 2 sec) 24
- (wait ~1min) 28

At the time, the log fills slowly - about ~100 bytes/sec, so each KByte should be visible...

- (8s) 32
- (12s) 36
- (12s) 40
- (12s) 44
- (10s) 52
- (12s) 60

Until there, I notice the displayed sizes are more multiples of 4K now, which could be the HDDs cluster size. I could understand that the file size could be displayed 'in blocksizes'.

- (30s later) 192

The `tail -f` of the file shows me the log is 'running normally' if i can say, and its size has a constant grow.

At this point, more than 10 minutes elapsed, and the log feed is pretty constant since the beginning.

- (12 min) 448 = 64x7
- (9 min) 960 = 64x15
- (20 min) 1984 = 64x31

Seems the values are now 64K x ((doubling pow of 2) -1)

- (24min, now logging more things) passing to 1284 ??? what ??? note : that's not a multiple of 64K
- (2 min) 2304 = 64x36
- (5min) 1820 ??? note : not a multiple of 64K

Tail shows the file growing without strange things... what the heck is happening ?

- (2min) 3840 = 64x60
- END of process
- (2 min) 2940 ??? not multiple of 64

Either i drank too much on New Year's Eve, but it is not even the case. Either there is something very special in all that, and I really want to know what happens there.

Comment: Can you confirm the sizes are actually doubling?  I can reproduce a similar issue but my file went from 4 to 8 to 12 (not 16).

Comment: @Jesse_b updated